# NGINX - Reverse proxy multiple API on different ports

Tags: api, nginx, port, reverse-proxy

I have the following API(s):

1. localhost:300/api/customers/
2. localhost:400/api/customers/:id/billing
3. localhost:500/api/orders

I'd like to use NGINX to have them all run under the following location:

localhost:443/api/

This seems very difficult because of customers spanning two servers.

Here's my failed attempt starting with orders

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name localhost;

    location /api/orders {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:500/api/orders;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}


server {
    listen 443;
    server_name localhost;

    location /api/customers/$id/billing {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:400/api/customers/$id/billing;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name localhost;

    location /api/customers {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:300/api/customers;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Anything jump out as far as a fix? Thanks!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The three services are being proxied by the same server (as far as `nginx` is concerned) so must be structured as three `location` blocks within one `server` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for details.

If you are just passing the original URI unmodified, you do not need to specify a URI on the `proxy_pass` statement.

```
server {
{
    listen 443;
    server_name localhost;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

    location /api/orders {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:500;
    }
    location /api/customers {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:400;
    }
    location = /api/customers {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:300;
    }
}
```

If the `proxy_set_header` statements are identical, they can be specified once in the parent block.

The type of `location` statement required is dependent on the range of URIs processed by the `localhost:300/api/customers/` service. If it is one URI, the `=` syntax will work. If it is any URI that does not match `/api/customers/:id/billing`, then you will need to use a regular expression location block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

I am not sure that this will work unless you terminate SSL here. That is configure the [reverse proxy as a secure server](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html).

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer did not work for me; I had three servers running as Kubernetes service mapped to different Cluster IP's (accessible only from Kubernetes nodes). So I used the host machine IP - `10.ttt.ttt.104`  and the following configuration so that I could access these services from my work network.

I am not an nginx expert by any length- but this worked -- so use it as base maybe

```
events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}
http{
    server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;

       server_name 10.ttt.ttt.104;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

       location / {
           proxy_pass http://10.103.152.188:80/;
       }
     }

    server {
       listen 9090;
       listen [::]:9090;

       server_name 10.ttt.ttt.104;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

       location / {
           proxy_pass http://10.107.115.44:9091/;
       }
     }

    server {
       listen 8080;
       listen [::]:8080;

       server_name 10.ttt.ttt.104;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

       location / {
           proxy_pass http://10.105.249.237:80/;
       }
     }
}
```

Comment: What you're doing is different. I needed to merge services running on different ports into one SSL endpoint.